Rust lifetime error with traits and casting
I'm getting this rust lifetime error, but I don't understand why it happens:
    error: lifetime may not live long enough
    --> src/console.rs:454:39
        |
    422 |     conn: &mut dyn ConnectionTrait<TlsStream<TcpStream>>,
        |     ----  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
        |     |
        |     has type `&mut dyn ConnectionTrait<'2, TlsStream<TcpStream>>`
    ...
    454 |       let logger = ConsoleLogger::new(conn);
        |                                       ^^^^ cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`

The (reduced) code looks like this:
    pub trait ConnectionTrait<'a, S>: Read + Write + BufRead + Send + Sync {
    }


    pub struct ConsoleLogger<'a> {
        conn: &'a mut dyn ConnectionTrait<'a, TlsStream<TcpStream>>,
    }

    impl<'a> ConsoleLogger<'a> {
        pub fn new(conn: &'a mut dyn ConnectionTrait<'a, TlsStream<TcpStream>>) -> Self {
            ConsoleLogger { conn }
        }
    }

    impl log::Log for ConsoleLogger<'_> {
        // ...
    }



    pub fn test123(logger: &dyn log::Log) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn cmd_test(&self, conn: &mut dyn ConnectionTrait<TlsStream<TcpStream>>) -> Result<Option<String>> {
        // some code...
        {
            let logger = ConsoleLogger::new(conn);
            if let Err(err) = test123(&logger) {
            bail!("failed: {}", err);
            }
        }

        Ok(Some(format!("ok")))
    }

To me clearly conn outlives logger, so I don't get why this error happens. How can it be fixed, in the most simple way?
